# get id of first div in page loaded via ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using $.get function for loading partial view:

```
$.get('/desk/nextstep', function (data) {
            var ids = $(data).filter(':first').attr('id');
            alert(ids);                
});
```

I want to get `id` of first(root) div, but this code not works:

```
var ids = $(data).filter(':first').attr('id');
```

I get `undefined` alert message. How to solve it?
Thanks.

**UPDATE:**
In the `data`  html code:

```
<div id="step1" class="scroll-pane">
    <div class="scroll_cont">
     //other content
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: What is within `data`? Post that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
$.get('/desk/nextstep', function (data) {
     var ids = $('<div/>').append(data).find(':first').attr('id');
     alert(ids);                
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use native method **match**. ;)

```
var ids = data.match(/id="([^"]+)"/);
```

Preview - http://jsfiddle.net/fsGe6/